# Cordova AdMob Plus - the ad opens only once while the application is running

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob

I have some problme, the ad opens only once while the application is running, I have no restrictions in the admob settings, When I turn off and then again turn on, then ad shows correctly but only once...
My code with admob looks like this:

```
        function onDeviceReady() {
            if(typeof window.admob === "object") {
                window.admob.interstitial.load({
                    id: {
                        android: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy'
                    },
                });
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

and in my application, I open ad like this:

```
window.admob.interstitial.show();
```

I use typeof instruction because I use this code on a common web page too, but like I checked this is no problem.
what can I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is working as intended.
After watching the first ad, you have to load the second (and every following) ad before you can show it.

```
window.admob.interstitial.load({
    id: {
        android: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy'
    },
});
```